# How do I wait for two cursorloaders to return with data before starting third dependent on the return data?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-fragments, android-loadermanager, android-cursorloader

I have an android app using fragments and a content provider to access my local sqlite database. The Listviews often depend on several database queries such that their display is based on the query results. Assuming I have three cursorloaders, how do I ensure loader 1 and 2 have both completed before running loader 3?

Comment: Give the `Loaders` unique ids (1, 2 and 3) and check the id of the `Loader` passed in to `onLoadFinished(...)`. Maintain global `booleans`, e.g., `boolean loader1Complete = false` and set them to `true` when in that method when they've completed. Then check to see if both `booleans` are `true` and start `Loader` number 3 if they are.

Answer (score 1):

Keep track of every loader that is started in a counter (`protected int loadersToRun,loadersCompleted=0;`) and have each of their `onLoadFinished` functions call

```
public void checkLoadersFinished(){
    loadersCompleted++
    if(loadersCompleted==loadersToRun){
        //Start loader 3
        loadersCompleted=0;
    }
}
```

If you need to make things work dynamically it can be accomplished by using a default case for  a set of loader IDs in the `onLoadFinished` and have that run `checkLoadersFinished`. We generate a unique ID for each loader using a Treeset to keep track of them and remove them on completion.